# Леска или лёска?

Tags: фонетика

Как правильно пишется (произносится): "леска" или "лёска" (через е или ё)? Речь о рыболовной снасти.

Answer (score 1):

Пишется **лЕска**. Произносится *[л'э]ска*, не *[л'о]ска*, причем во всех падежных формах (Новый орфоэпический словарь русского языка Т.Ф.Ивановой).